# Checking if a 2D Array includes this field or if it is undefined

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Currently working on a little game for my last task for the university.
My current problem is that the gameboard is a  `2D Array of Cells` (selfmade-class). The board is created with a txt.file I read in. Now there are multiple commands the user can type in. One command is to create a new Game Object and place it on the board using specific x and y parameters.
Is there any way to check if the field is big enough for the parameters they entered besides this one:

```
try {
        gameField.getField()[Integer
        parseInt(splittedCom[1])][Integer
        parseInt(splittedCom[2])].getStatus();
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { 
        Terminal.printLine("Error, this cell isn't in the gameField");
    }
```

I'm currently using this to check it for another command. Is there a way to use this without an Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your array is already constructed, you should have the dimensions of the array already, so you would use `gameBoard.length` for the width and `gameBoard[0].length` for the height, and use those to compare with whatever it is that the user has provided.

EDIT: As per your question:

If you have your `gameBoard` object accessible, you would not need to save them, since that information would be available through the `gameBoard` object itself. Alternatively, you would have to persist them some way. Note that although you are *wasting* some extra memory to store the values, throwing exceptions also has its cost, and should be avoided (in this case). A situation where you expect the user to provide incorrect values does not fall under the criterion of an exception case, since that is something you expect.

Comment: I also thought about saving both lengths so I could use them but with your method saving the lengths when the field is created would be a "waste"? I want my code to be as clear and optimal as possible. You think saving them or accessing them via `gameBoard.length` and `gameBoard[0].length` is better style?

Comment: @NhatNienne: I have updated my answer. You do raise a valid point, but you need to keep in mind the cost of throwing exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me. Helped me out alot!

Comment: @NhatNienne: You're welcome. I have modified my answer a bit more, might be better if you go through it once again just in case.

Comment: Normally Such things as an `Integer.parseInt() NumberFormatException` could always be checked with an `regex` to avoid using Exceptions am I right?

Comment: @NhatNienne: Yes that would help going around errors. If you are using GUI components, you should also find components which specifically expect numerical values and will not allow the user to continue should they provide otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Check the input as long as it fits into your gamefield.

```
boolean checker = false;
    while(!checker){
     if( /* check if the input is inside the gamefield */){
        checker = true;
        }
    }
```